# Saving image file field manually in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I am trying to save a preview image generated by "preview_generator" Python app.

[image: Model]

But I am getting IntegrityError duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_material_pkey". I've tried many things but nothing seems to be working.

If I call super at the end of save I don't get material_file url or path.

Answer (score 0):

remove this line `material = self`  in your code and use below way

```
obj = super(Material, self).save(force_update=False, using=None,update_fields=None)
material = obj
```

Comment: I've even tried material=Material.object.get(id=self.id). but didn't work, but I will give this a try tomorrow.

Comment: didn't work 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'material_file'

Comment: I think your object is not saving when you call super method. remove self parameter in save method of super